# How can I call play wav file in Silverlight 3?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How can I play a wav file in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check this MSDN blog article
[Playing back Wave files in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/gillesk/archive/2009/03/23/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight.aspx)